# Invalid json float conversion depending on server

Tags: c, json, serialization

I wrote a C library that returns some JSON strings using the [json-c](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.17/doc/html/index.html) library. This library is used by a Tomcat Java server (through JNI), and the JSON is passed to a client browser and parsed by a JavaScript there. **On one server, everything works fine**. We replicate that server onto another machine, and there there is some garbage in the JSON. For instance:

```
{ "Data": [ -5.3014e+05, -5.3022e+05.0, -5.3028e+05, -5.3023e+05, -5.3031e+05 ], "Name": "MonitorCurrent @ circuit_17", "Desc": "ADC averaged value 24bit" }
```

This ...e+05.0 breaks the parsing. I'm stumped by what could be the cause. <strike>The only thing I can think of is some multithreading problem, but all the statics are thread-local, and anyway</strike> the only error I've found so far is this .0 added to some exponents.

I used the following serialization:

```
json_c_set_serialization_double_format("%.5g", JSON_C_OPTION_GLOBAL);
```

EDIT: I have the same error if I call the lib directly from C, so the problem has nothing to do with Java/Javascript/Tomcat/Multithreading/.... It's only between C, json-c and the machine. The working one is Centos 8.5, the other is openSUSE Leap.

Comment: `-5.3022e+05.0` is not valid JSON, but you probably already knew that.

Comment: `s/On one server, everything works fine./On one server, no errors are observed/g`  Just because you don't observe any errors does not mean it "works fine".  That's especially true for multithreaded race conditions.

Comment: that's how the *g* format is defined in `printf()`. From man: Style e is used if the exponent from its conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision. Does json-c allow usiing `%.5f` ?

Comment: Andrew, I can reproduce it in C, so no multithreading involved at all. Yes, I could use %.5f, but don't want to because of the wide range of the data.

Comment: I tried with %.5e and the error still happens sometimes. With %.5f, no error seen yet.

Comment: have you already tried printiing a value that results in `...e+05.0` directly with `printf()` ?

Comment: It's definitely a bug in libjson-c. If I use the serialization option JSON_C_TO_STRING_NOZERO then the invalid data becomes ...`,1.245e+06.,`... (yes there's a dot after the exponent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in libjson-c 0.13. If I link with 0.15 or 0.17, there's no problem.